# Installing python library dependency without Internet available

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install the following package (SignXML) on Windows Server 2012: https://pypi.org/project/signxml/

I am running Python 2.7.14, it's an isolated server which is only accessible within Intranet and has all outbound connections blocked.

I've downloaded tar.gz of that package and executed: "pip install signxml-2.6.0.tar.gz".

It started installation but I get error:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))
>   after connec tion broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to
>   pypi.python. org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/lxml/

I am no expert with Python but I assume based on error that it attempts to retrieve some dependancy from pypi but fails as the outbound connections are blocked.

Is there a way to see all dependencies for that project (SignXML) and manually download them as tar.gz archives and then somehow manually install them or tell SignXML install to use local files instead of fetching them from Pypi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Answer (score 0):

I can understand you want to install signxml without internet as you downloaded .tar.gz file. But it requires some other dependencies too.

As per documentation https://pypi.org/project/signxml/

You will need to install other packages as -  lxml, defusedxml, cryptography, eight, pyOpenSSL.

Please refer the documentation carefully.!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to be honest. Whether the file is a tar.gz, a .whl, or a straight up install call (like pip install pygame), it downloads it from the internet. The only way I could think of doing offline, is by extracting the contents you have and placing them in the

```
[python install dir]/Lib/site-packages
```

directory in it's own folder.

Answer (score -1):

In the [setup.py](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml/blob/master/setup.py) file of the package are the required packages listed. You probably need to install all of them manually.